# How to pass `__init_subclass__` keyword arguments when using `type`?

Tags: python, metaclass

I have a class that accepts keyword arguments, something that was introduced together with `__init_subclass__` in Python 3.6:

```py
class Parent:
  def __init_subclass__(cls, key=None, **kwargs):
    super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
    assert key is not None

class Child(Parent, key=5):
  pass

Child2 = type("Child2", (Parent,), {})
```

But it gives an `AssertionError` since no `key` was passed. If I try to give an additional dictionary of arguments I get the following error:

```
>>> type("Child2", (Parent,), {}, {"key": 5})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments
```

And also the documentation on the [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function do not allow for them to be specified. How can I pass these kwargs to `__init_subclass__`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass keyword arguments to the `type()` call:

```py
Child2 = type("Child2", (base,), {}, key=5)
```

This has been available together with `__init_subclass__` since Python 3.6.0 but is actually an oversight in the Python documentation. It has been corrected in the Python 3.10 development docs ([here](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#type)) whose `type()` signature shows you how to do it:

```
type(name, bases, dict, **kwds)
```

And states this possibility:

> Keyword arguments provided to the three argument form are passed to the appropriate metaclass machinery (usually `__init_subclass__()`) in the same way that keywords in a class definition (besides metaclass) would.